# create pageContext from HttpServletRequest

Tags: web-applications, page-lifecycle, servlets

I know this might sound crazy...but i am integrating with some third party api's and unfortunately they have a utility class which only takes a pageContext object..I did some peeking around and found that they are doing a lot of stuff with pageContext... Is there a way to get to or create a pageContext from HttpServeletRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [MockPageContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockPageContext.html) from the Spring API. It's designed for testing, but it would do a fine job of fooling the app into thinking it was the real thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but Unfortunaley that solution ...I don't want to fool my app....

Comment: Fooling your app is exactly what you're trying to do. You don't have a PageContext, and you want to simulate one. MockPageContext is a perfectly valid implementation of PageContext, you're going to have to use something like it anyway. Might as well use one that's already written.

Comment: well the point that you are making is correct...but i am still not sure...will fool around with some workarounds a bit..